# IOError: [Errno 22] for File Name With Chinese Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting an error in my Python project when trying to open().read() a file whose name contains Chinese characters. Here is the error i'm getting:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\Document
s\\Desktop\\Test2\\projects\\cplusplus-practices-2011\\ cplusplus-practices-2011
\\??????.cpp'
```

Where ??????.cpp is a file name made of Chinese characters.

Here is the line that the error occurs on:

```
source_file = open(dir_file,'rb').read()
```

What do I need to do in order for Python to be able to open or read files with Chinese characters in the file name?

Comment: Is your directory name supposed to start with a space?